# Tokenize a string based off of another string

Tags: c

I'm making a differential equation solver sort of program using C, where the user is expected to enter input as a variable separable differential equation in the form of F(y)dy= G(x)dx
Tokenizing F(y) and G(x) based on arithmetic operators is not an issue. However, my plan was also to split F(y) and G(x) from dy and dx.

So, the root question thus becomes, " How do I split a string based off of another string, in C?"

I tried using strtok for the same, but that obviously doesn't work, because if I pass "dx" as the delimiter, the string gets tokenized at every occurrence of either d or x.

I'm not sure if there are any predefined functions to do the same(I'm an amateur when it comes to C), so if anyone has any smart way to use strtok or any other user-defined function/ algorithm for the same, kindly help out :)

Thank you!!

Comment: Use [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find the position of `"dx"` and `"dy"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to parse a string for sub-strings.
With a starting pointer and a span, the results could be copied to other memory with `strncpy`.
The initial string is not modified so another parsing strategy could be applied as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char text[] = "F(y)dy= G(x)dx";
    char *parse = text;
    int span = 0;

    while ( *parse) {
        parse += strspn ( parse, ")= ");//skip leading delimiters
        span = strcspn ( parse, ")= ");//count to next delimiter
        span += strspn ( parse + span, ")");//to include trailing )
        printf ( "%.*s\n", span, parse);
        parse += span;//advance the pointer
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
F(y)
dy
G(x)
dx
```